# An error occurred while importing the package（m1 macbook pro)

Tags: python

ImportError: C extension: dlopen(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))) not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.

How to roslove this problem？

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, it is a problem with the virtual environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).